# Wordpress: How to deregister script from specific templates

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, operators

I would like to know how to exclude google map api script for the following templates but load on the rest of the site:

```
function my_register_javascript() {

  if ( !is_post_type_archive( 'impact' ) || !is_post_type_archive( 'deal' ) || !is_post_type_archive( 'local' ) || !is_tax( 'directory' )) {

    wp_register_script( 'googlemapsapi', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyD-DQkeStHf3xm9e0ibSPcVGDLlaSTwWEA&region=US&language=EN'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('googlemapsapi');  
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_javascript', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is in your template file code use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script and or https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script as needed before you call get_header();

You could add a conditional around the enqueue script but there is no need if you have an actual template page - and it saves running a query on every other page.